# What is right way to handle UITextField on a static (non scroll) page?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a drill-down page that fits the screen exactly, so I did not used a Scroll View.  But I have an UITextField down near the bottom and when the keyboard shows up, you can't see what you are typing.

So was wondering what is standard...Should I use a Scroll View and then will iOS scroll up?

I tried to do this as a test but I am not (yet) able to add a "Scroll View" in the right way to get it to work.  I kinda think if I started over and added all the controls over from scratch, I would work...but there has to be a way to convert...

First I tried to edit "View" "custom class" class property and type "Scroll View"  Would have been great if it was that easy...but xcode thought it was still a view.

Then I tried to select all of my controls in the "View" and from Editor->Embed In->Scroll View menu.  This seemed to work as it recognized that it is a real "Scroll View", but I get this error: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate."

Then I created a property of "IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView" and tried to hook it up, but at this point, I am just guessing...I did add the "UIScrollViewDelegate" to the UIViewController of my class...

There are lots of posts about this error string, but I can't find a solution that works for storyboards and adding a scroll view to an existing (working) view.

I realize it is hard to help w/o me providing any code...but much of it seems to be how I setup the UI...

If you got any thoughts, send 'em my way!

thx!

Comment: useful links : http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view doesn't need to scroll normally, then don't make it a scroll view. Simply animate the frame of the views you need to get out of the way.

I have an [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135248/logic-for-moving-text-field-above-keyboard-on-tap/9136698#9136698) that you should check out, it has a lot of sample code in it that will hopefully get you on your way.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If you can link to another answer that answers this question, then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: The linked answer is great, though :)

Comment: @jrturton understood, and thank you! When these come up should I simply state that it's a possible duplicate in the comments? Or also flag for moderator attention? I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Flag as a duplicate - can comment too so that the questioner can see the linked question straight away. When you can cast close votes, the comment is auto-added. At the rate and quality you're going at, it wont be long before you've enough rep to do that!

Comment: Thanks all, didn't realize that was the way to do it.