# Detect if iOS device's keyboard has the "keyboard hiding button", like on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

The default software keyboard on iOS when running on an iPad has a "**dismiss**" button to hide the keyboard. It's located in the bottom-right corner.

**Is there a way to detect specifically this configuration... or that this button exists... aside from checking whether the device is an iPad or not?** For example, for devices WITHOUT this button (iPhone/iPod Touch), maybe we would want to add a button outside of the keyboard to do this, but wouldn't want two separate buttons to exist if there was one already on iPad.

[image: iPad software keyboard photo]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that exist a way to specifically ask if a keyboard supports its, but what you can do is ask the idiom of device:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

}
else {

}
```

Or, since also 6 and 6plus supports that button in landscape you can ask the [`UITraitCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/) of the device in that specific moment, if it is regular the dismiss button on the keyboard will be displayed, but is kind of a strong hypothesis.
Before presenting the keyboard try to check horizontal traits.

```
if view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular {
        // has the dismiss button
    }
    else {
        // add an accessory input view
    }
```

Comment: It says in the question above "Is there a way to detect specifically this configuration... or that this button exists... **aside from checking whether the device is an iPad or not?**"

Comment: @BenGuild Checking traits is not checking device, besides we are trying to help, downvoting won't

Comment: Your source code includes checking for a match with `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`.

Comment: yes the other one was a suggestion. I've update my answer with a snippet , SWIFT since you did not specify the language.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "keyboard hide button"?

Comment: @Llg It doesn't seems possible, unless you build a custom keyboard and a user installs and uses it

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there a way to detect when this button is tapped without the `NSNotificationCenter ` way? Because I did the same as the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322137/uikeyboardwillhide-not-triggered but when i tap the button my app crashes

Answer (score -1):

You can set below things

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

or

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

and other different types

Comment: That's not what's being asked. I'm asking if there's a way to see if the button exists, not if it has been pressed.