# Dealing with keyboard and tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

The layout for one of my View Controllers is such: I have a scroll view embedded inside my VC. Inside my scroll view, I have a table view that consists of 5 cell. The first 3 cells consist of a textfield thats pulls its text from a dictionary and this changes depending on certain situations. These textfields are editable and so tapping on them brings up the keyboard, the issue however is that I would like my view to scroll when I tap on the text field because right now they keyboard hides the the third editable text field. Another issue is that at the moment, clicking outside teh table view doesnt cause the keyboard to be dismissed and so the only way of dismissing the keyboard is tapping on the return key. What I would like to happen is that when I tap on either one of the 3 editable fields, the scroll view ought to scroll up  a certain number that I define (this is so that I can define how much to scroll depending on which row is currently selected). One of the issues I'm facing is that I can't directly reference these textfields in my VC since they're all created through one prototype cell. My thinking was that I could create a dictionary with the 3 textfields as keys and then the scrollview y coordinates as values and then use that. However , I wasn't sure how to do this in my situation (with the prototype cells). Would really appreciate if someone could show me some sample code on how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logic For Moving Text Field Above Keyboard On Tap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135248/logic-for-moving-text-field-above-keyboard-on-tap)

Comment: This solution doesn't really work for me. This doesn't help me deal with my prototype cells and the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your text fields by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get the UITableViewCell, then calling `viewWithTag:` to get your UITextField. Just assign the text fields a tag number. Also, set the text field's delegate to be your view controller so that you can respond to a user tapping to edit text.